# Geometry proof given diagram

Tags: geometry

[image]

$ABCD$ forms a square. $CDE$ forms a triangle. Given $\measuredangle AED=15^{\circ}$ and $DE=CE$, prove $\triangle CDE$ is equilateral.

The question is surprising hard, the problem is basically proving $\measuredangle BAE=\measuredangle AEB$. Can I have some hint.

Comment: In your diagram the lettering for points $B,C$ is a bit faint, maybe fix that and include the diagram actually in the question, not just a link.

Comment: I'll link a clearer picture, I don't have enough reputation to directly post pic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Each possible length of $DE$ both is uniquely determined by and uniquely determines angle $\measuredangle CDE$. Likewise, $\measuredangle DEA$ is uniquely determined by and uniquely determines either one of the length $DE$ or $\measuredangle CDE$. This means that we can reverse the problem! Thus "Prove that if triangle $CDE$ is equilateral, $\measuredangle DEA=15^{\circ}$" is an equivalent problem. This is much easier. Proof:

1) Triangle $DEA$ is isoceles (since $DE=AD$)

2)$\measuredangle ADE=(90+60)^{\circ}=150^{\circ}$

3)$\measuredangle DEA=((180-150)/2)^{\circ}=15^{\circ}$

And we are done.

Comment: @dxiv Thank you, it has been fixed!

Comment: That's very nice, didn't see the equivalence in question!

Answer (score 0):

Ok ! Here we go ..

$ABCD$ is a square.
That means -> $AB=BC=CD=AD$

Now if you carefully notice, $CD$ is the base of the $\Delta CDE$

Given that $DC = DE$

We can conclude that $\Delta ADE$ is an isosceles triangle.
Therefore ,
$\angle AED = \angle EAD$

So, $\angle EAD = 15º$

Now, By Angle-Sum Property in $\Delta ADE$

$\angle AED + \angle EAD + \angle ADE = 180º $

=> $\angle ADE = 150º $

=> $90º + \angle CDE = 150º$

=> $\angle CDE = 60º$

Also you can notice that $\Delta DCE$ isosceles.
Therefore ,

$\angle DEC = \angle DCE$

By Angle-Sum Property in $\Delta DEC$

$\angle CDE + \angle DCE + \angle CED = 180º$

=> $60º + \angle DCE + \angle DCE = 180º$

=> $2\angle DCE = 120º$

=> $\angle DCE = 60º$

Therefore,

$\angle CDE = \angle DCE = \angle CED = 60º$

So $\Delta DCE$ is equilateral !

Hence Proved

Comment: I guess .. The rest is easy for you

Comment: The given was DE=CE, not DC=DE. Is this proof even possible actually.

Comment: Oh Sorry .. Misread it ... Will get back to you after correcting it

Comment: (And he never did...)

Comment: The fact that the triangle DEC is isosceles is given. But it is left to prove that it is also equilateral. We know that DE=CE, but we need to prove that these two sides are also equal to the third side (which happens to be the side of a square, so we can as well prove the equality of DE or CE to any of the sides of that square whatsoever, since they're all equal anyway), or that the angle contained between CE and DE is 60° (because an isosceles triangle with the vertex angle 60° is also equilateral). And this is exactly where the "hard" part of this problem lies.